# SQL Server Component Constraint or Constraint for more than 1 column

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I want to create a table with operational details like:

```
CRAETED_ON DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
CREATED_BY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DELETED_ON DATETIME NULL,
DELETED_BY VARCHAR(10) NULL
```

I want to put constraint `IF DELETED_ON` is updated then they should provide the `DELETED_BY`.

BOTH should be NULL or both should not be NULL are allowed. One NULL & other NOT NULL is not allowed.

Comment: when I had a similar requirement, I used triggers (needed to be different for all CRUD operations) which gives you great flexibility, including using the server to generate the time and user context so we don't reply on the client.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished with a table level check constraint, assuming you want the constraint to apply to both inserts and updates:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example(
    CREATED_ON  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    CREATED_BY  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    DELETED_ON  DATETIME NULL,
    DELETED_BY  VARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT IF_DELETED_ON CHECK ((DELETED_ON IS NULL AND DELETED_BY IS NULL) OR  (DELETED_ON IS NOT NULL AND DELETED_BY IS NOT NULL))
);
```